# React setstate not firing to close MUI dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

My dialog used from Material UI has been set up in its own component unlike the demos provided - https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/

I can open the dialog and the state changes from false to true. I've added a handleClose for the close which should set the state back to false... but comes back true again. Can anybody point out to what I've done wrong here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/zlmj2k3pom

```
this.state = {
  open: false
};

state = {
  open: false
};

handleClose = () => {
  this.setState({ open: false });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the `open` state in the `VehicleDialog` component you can use the `open` and `onClose` props given to it to close the modal.

**Example**

```
class VehicleDialog extends Component {
  render() {
    const { open, id, onClose } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Dialog aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title" open={open}>
          <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title">Modal title</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom>
              Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
              dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
              ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
            </Typography>
            <Typography gutterBottom>
              Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur
              et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor
              auctor.
            </Typography>
            <Typography gutterBottom>
              Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo
              cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio
              dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
            </Typography>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={() => onClose(id)}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `open` variable from props in your render, so changing `state.open` has no effect.

```
  render() {
    const { open, id } = this.props;
```

I suggest you to do next things:

1. Set `state = { open: this.props.open }` in constructor
2. Then use `state.open` variable in render function